# Add records from different gridview in one common gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to get records(with price column) from 2 different gridviews,display them in 3rd gridview and find the total every time..Are there examples which implements this one?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single gridview and combine the datasource into the different gridview items. to get total you can bind a function to the value field.

let us know if you need any more info.